# WordPress multisite redirect on digital ocean

Tags: multisite

I built a multisite install on digitalocean out here http://139.59.80.67 ,

then when I tried to point my domain to the site, I get a redirect to http://139.59.80.67/wp-signup.php?new=pataka.co

this is the code on WP-config.php

```
 define('WP_DEBUG', false);

define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '139.59.80.67');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

and this is the code on .httaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the settings in Settings, General to the new domain  http://www.example.com ?

**added**

Other things to check are if your nameservers for your domain are correct, according to your hosting requirements. And note that nameserver changes might take a while to propagate (become valid) for some locations.

Also, check your browser cache. Or start a new 'private' browser session and try your domain.

Comment: I tried that but does not help